# How do I get the Icons back on the panel bar on the Raspberry Pi4

Tags: raspbian

I some how deleted all the Icons in the panel bar and also in the panel preferences applets window on the Pi4.

Comment: Re-install lxpanel with right preferences or re install everything after taking a backup.

Comment: Thanks, Could you tell how to do that? I am really new at this so I need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually tried this, but I would delete `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels` (backup first to be sure - but you probably can't make it worse).

AFAIK if you reboot LXDE should re-create the default.

If this fails you could copy from `/etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel`